# Delete accidental tag?

Tags: support

With new privileges come new mistakes:

I accidentally and unintentionally just created a bad tag and am unable to delete it:

[harry-potte](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potte)

Is this a higher level moderation level that can take care of it?

Comment: Should disappear on it's own once the system catches it with zero questions.  Dunno when that cycle runs though.

Comment: ...about 24 hours.

Comment: ....aaaand it's gone

Answer (score 9):

**Don't worry about it. These things happen, and the system will take care of it for you.**

> Tags not associated with any question are automatically destroyed at 03:00 UTC every day.
>
> Tags which are misspelled should have the questions under them retagged to the appropriate tag, which will result in the misspelled tag's destruction due to having no uses.
>
> <sub>-- [main meta FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/278659)</sub>